# Reason for "java.lang.NullPointerException" in my case?

Tags: java, exception, compiler-errors, chat, rsa

I have a little problem. I'm trying to bulid really simple RSA chat in java. But I don't know what correct in my code to avoid problems. When I run chat_Server.java, then chat_Client.java and send text it freezes, doesn't responding. And when I run only chat_Server.java, and send sth, then :

(chat_Serwer.java:92) **ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());**

(chat_Serwer.java:13) **public class chat_Serwer extends javax.swing.JFrame {**

(chat_Serwer.java:53) **msg_sendActionPerformed(evt);** in GUI initComponents()

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at chat.chat_Serwer.msg_sendActionPerformed(chat_Serwer.java:92)
at chat.chat_Serwer.access$100(chat_Serwer.java:13)
at chat.chat_Serwer$2.actionPerformed(chat_Serwer.java:53)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

> **I'm begging for help.**

Declaration:

```
public static int BIT_LENGTH = 1024;

static ServerSocket ss;
static Socket s;

static ObjectInputStream ois;
static ObjectOutputStream oos;
```

Action on button in Server.java:

```
private void msg_sendActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    try{
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        //reading

        Message mess = (Message) ois.readObject();
        BigInteger d = mess.d;
        BigInteger n = mess.n;
        BigInteger e = mess.e;
        System.out.println("d: "+d);
        System.out.println("n: "+n);
        System.out.println("e: "+e);

        String msgout = "";
        msgout = msg_text.getText().trim();

        // conversion String to BigInteger
        String txt = msgout;
        byte[] msBytes = txt.getBytes();
        BigInteger msg = new BigInteger(msBytes);
        System.out.println(msg);

        // Encryption
        BigInteger enc = msg.modPow(e, n);

        // sending

        Message mes = new Message();
        mes.enc = enc;
        oos.writeObject(mes);
        oos.flush();

        }catch(IOException ex){
                System.out.println("w przycisku: "+ex.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(chat_Serwer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Main in Server.java

```
  // Prime numbers
      Random rand = new SecureRandom();
      BigInteger p = new BigInteger(BIT_LENGTH / 2, 100, rand);
      BigInteger q = new BigInteger(BIT_LENGTH / 2, 100, rand);


      BigInteger n = p.multiply(q);
      BigInteger phi = p.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)
              .multiply(q.subtract(BigInteger.ONE));


      BigInteger e;
      do e = new BigInteger(phi.bitLength(), rand);
      while (e.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) <= 0
              || e.compareTo(phi) >= 0
              || !e.gcd(phi).equals(BigInteger.ONE));
      BigInteger d = e.modInverse(phi);



    try{
        ss = new ServerSocket(8080); //choose port
        s = ss.accept(); 

       //sending
        Message mes = new Message();
        mes.d = d;
        mes.n = n;
        mes.e = e;
        oos.writeObject(mes);
        oos.flush();

        //reading
        Message mess = (Message) ois.readObject();
        BigInteger enc = mess.enc;

         //decryption
         BigInteger dec = enc.modPow(d, n);
         String wejscie = new String(dec.toByteArray());

         msg_area.setText(msg_area.getText().trim()+"\n Serwer: "+wejscie); //shows message

    }catch( IOException z){
        System.out.println("w main: "+z);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(chat_Serwer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Message.java

```
package chat;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Message implements Serializable {

   public BigInteger e;
   public BigInteger d;
   public BigInteger n;
   public BigInteger enc;
   public BigInteger dec;  
}
```

Client.java is almost the same. I'm only not sending e, d, n to Message.java, but read them.

Comment: Which line is `chat_Serwer.java:92`?

Comment: I've just added it in post :).

Comment: You're not showing where you declare `s`, but presumably it hasn't been initialized.

Comment: Pardon me. I declare **static ServerSocket ss;** and **static Socket s;** :)